# How to deny the access when current_user tries to sign_up in acl9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using acl9 with authlogic in my rails3 app. I would like to know how to -

1. prevent the current_user when he tries to create the new user?
2. allow the superadmin to create the new user?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear on your question.  If you just want to know that a given user is logged in, in the controller method that displays the form to a new user check to see if `current_user` is set, and if so, set a flash message saying so.  Example, in, perhaps `registrations_controller.rb`

```
# show an empty registration form to user
def new
  if current_user
    flash[:notice] = "Hey #{current_user.name}, you're already logged in!"
    return
  end
  ... rest of normal controller code to create a registration form
end
```

If you want to prevent a non-admin user from creating new users, you'll need to check their role, e.g.

```
unless current_user.has_role? :superadmin
  flash[:warning] = "Sorry #{current_user.name}, I can't do that for you."
  return
end
```